# How can I fix colour selection of a pressed button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

HTTP:

```
<label class="instructions" for="hidden_x"> Insert X: </label>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="1" id="x_1" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 1"> 1 </button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="2" id="x_2" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 2"> 2 </button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="3" id="x_3" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 3"> 3 </button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="4" id="x_4" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 4"> 4 </button>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_x" id="hidden_x" value=""> <br>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
let buttonsX = document.getElementsByName("button_x");
for (let i = 0; i < buttonsX.length; i++) {
    buttonsX[i].onclick = function (event) {
        document.getElementById("hidden_x").value = event.target.value;
        buttonsX.forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("focused"));
        /*event.target.classList.add("focused");*/
        this.classList.add('focused');
    }
}
}
```

CSS:

```
.button .focused{
background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

When I press the button its colour doesn't change. How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Commented JavaScript line is one more option that I tried to use.

Comment: remove the space between `.button.focused`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your css is saying find the `.focused` class inside the `.button` so its not changing the color. Removing the space between two classes will help.

```js
window.onload = function(){
let buttonsX = document.getElementsByName("button_x");
for (let i = 0; i < buttonsX.length; i++) {
    buttonsX[i].onclick = function (event) {
        document.getElementById("hidden_x").value = event.target.value;
        buttonsX.forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("focused"));
        this.classList.add('focused');
    }
}
}
```

```css
.button.focused{
background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<label class="instructions" for="hidden_x"> Insert X: </label>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="1" id="x_1" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 1"> 1 </button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="2" id="x_2" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 2"> 2 </button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="3" id="x_3" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 3"> 3 </button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button_x" value="4" id="x_4" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = 4"> 4 </button>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_x" id="hidden_x" value=""> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method....
onclick="document.getElementById("sent Id of the button").

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.mystyle {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.mystyle1 {
  width: 20%;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: 25px;
}
</style>
<button class="mystyle1" id="x_1" onblur="myFunction(id)" onfocus="myFunction(id,'focus')">Click me</button>
<button class="mystyle1" id="x_2"onblur="myFunction(id)" onfocus="myFunction(id,'focus')">Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction(ou,type) {
var element = document.getElementById(ou);
  if(type=="focus"){
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
    element.classList.remove("mystyle1");
}
else{
    element.classList.add("mystyle1");
    element.classList.remove("mystyle");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Do dynamic...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it will be useful for others who are interested in the topic.

Comment: Actually, there was some other logic in the programme: that's why technique which was used in my question is quite complicated.